# F# Async.AwaitEvent and COM interop events

Tags: f#, event-handling, com-interop

I have a COM object, which I connect to, and I should recieve an event, which would confirm that connection is established. I write code and test it in F# interactive, and for some reason it wouldn't catch COM events when I use `Async.RunSynchronously`.

```
/// This class wraps COM event into F# Async-compatible event
type EikonWatcher(eikon : EikonDesktopDataAPI) =
    let changed = new Event<_>()
    do eikon.add_OnStatusChanged (fun e -> changed.Trigger true)
    member self.StatusChanged = changed.Publish

/// My method
let ``will that connection work?`` () = 
    let eikon = EikonDesktopDataAPIClass() :> EikonDesktopDataAPI // create COM object
    let a = async {
        let watcher = EikonWatcher eikon // wrap it 
        eikon.Initialize() |> ignore     // send connection request
        let! result =  Async.AwaitEvent watcher.StatusChanged // waiting event
        printfn "%A" result              // printing result
        return result
    }

    // I use either first or second line of code, not both of them
    Async.Start (Async.Ignore a)            // does not hang, result prints 
    Async.RunSynchronously (Async.Ignore) a // hangs!!!


/// Running
``will that connection work?`` ()
```

At the same time, code works perfectly well with `RunSynchronously` when I insert it into console app.
What should I do so that to prevent that nasty behavior?

Comment: Threading is not a minor detail to COM components.  The F# interactive console no doubt uses [STAThread] on its entrypoint, promising to provide support to single-threaded COM objects.  A console app does not, it is [MTAThread] by default.  Which forces COM to create another thread to give the COM component a hospitable home.  Most important thing such a thread does is pump a message loop.  Not sure what RunSynchronously() does, apparently *not* pump a message loop.  So it just deadlocks since the COM component can't fire its event.

Comment: Well, generally speaking, I believe that's exactly the case. But, I still have no idea how could I fix it (

Comment: Does this *have* to run in the interactive F# console?  You can start a thread to run this code, gets COM to solve your problem again.

Comment: @HansPassant running stuff in FSI is pretty much a standard part of F# development.  Not being able to do that would be a pretty big handicap.

Comment: isn't it the case that runsynchronously will wait, but since it waits, the message pump does not process (if [STAThread] => shared pump), and the COM will never have a chance to send the message ?

Comment: @nicolas erm, maybe... but how do I check it out?

Answer (score 1):

The code we write under within a single Thread (as in STA) **feels** like it is made of independant pieces each having their own life, but this is actually **a fallacy** : everything is mediated under a common ***event loop***, which "linearizes" the various calls.

So everything we do, unless explicitely spoecified otherwise, is essentially single threaded and you can not wait for yourself without creating a deadlock.

When you specify `Async.Start` it does start a new, independant computation which runs on its own, a "thread".

Whereas When you call runsynchronously, it awaits on the same 'thread'.

Now if the event you are waiting, which **feels** like an independant thing, is actually 'linearized' by the **same** event loop, you are actually waiting for yourself, hence the deadlock.

---

Something useful if you want to wait "asynchronously", (aka wait for an event, but not actually block and leave the opportunity for any other task to perform work) you can use the following code within your async block :

```
async {
         ....
         let! token = myAsyncTask |> Async.StartChild
         let! result = token
         ....  
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for suggestion, unfortunately using children tasks or asyncs doesn't solve the problem, the program behavior didn't change

Comment: how strange. if I try with excel /COM I should reproduce